# IIF statement in ssrs getting #Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

When i Put IIF statement in my cell it give #Error at my cells.

```
**=IIF(Year(Fields!Date.Value) <= 2015 AND Month(Fields!End_Date.Value) <= 02 AND Lookup(Fields!Project.Value,Fields!Project.Value,Fields!company.Value, "ds_Projects")="ABC", "Available", "No")**
```

i want if condition is true print Available, if false then print No.

Comment: I think it might be an error in you're LookUp Function. Not necessarily the syntax but maybe a field being checked. Try taking that part out of the IIF stmt and see if you still get an #Error just as a test.

Comment: Thanx for your reply JT2ouan... you mean that i use Switch statment...?

Comment: No...Where did you get 'use a switch stmt' from my comment? Try this IIF stmt and see if oyu get #Error. =IIF(Year(Fields!Date.Value) <= 2015 AND Month(Fields!End_Date.Value) <= 02, "Available", "No")

Comment: when i use IIF statement without LOOKUP then it give me good result mean it is printing "available" and "NO" but not working with lookup...why its happen plz help me.. lookup fields are necessary in my case....Jt2ouan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combining your OR IIF into the first one.

```
=IIF((Year(Fields!Date.Value) <= 2015 AND Month(Fields!End_Date.Value) <= 02 AND
 Lookup(Fields!Project.Value,Fields!Project.Value,Fields!company.Value, "ds_Projects")="ABC") 
 OR (Lookup(fields!a.value, fields!a.value, fileds!bill.value, "ds_projects")="xyz"), "Available", "No")
```

Comment: Thanx Jt2ouan for reply... i think it is not problem in fact i am using two IIF statement with "OR" operator in my single expression and both IIF have lookup functions... when i delete my one IIF statement then it work good but when i run both IIF together in single expression it is not working... i think now you are understanding my problem... plz give me solution ..thanx

Comment: =IIF(Year(Fields!Date.Value) <= 2015 AND Month(Fields!End_Date.Value) <= 02 AND Lookup(Fields!Project.Value,Fields!Project.Value,Fields!company.Value, "ds_Projects")="ABC", "Available", "No")

OR

IIF(Lookup(fields!a.value, fields!a.value, fileds!bill.value, "ds_projects")="xyz", "available", "No")

Comment: You didn't mention you had two IIF's in your original question.